# Leaflet toolTip-display is a function of layer order

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers, overlay

My map creates 3 Leaflet GeoJSON layers representing state, county, and town features collections. Each feature (in each layer) is bound to a tooltip by the onEachFeature option. The toolTip displays the name of the feature (state, county, or town).

For example:

```
   var ME_Towns_Layer = L.geoJSON(METowns,{
      style:         Style_ME_Towns,
         onEachFeature: function (feature, layer)
         {
            layer.bindTooltip(
               feature.properties.TOWN,
               {
                  permanent:   false,
                  direction:  'center',
                  className:  'tooltip_style',
                  interactive: true
               }
            )
         }
   });
```

The 3 layers are selected (by the user) via the overlay check boxes within the layer control.

```
   var overlays = {
     "US states":    US_States_Layer,
     "ME counties":  ME_Counties_Layer,
     "ME towns":     ME_Towns_Layer
   };
   L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

When any single layer is selected in the layer-control (and added to the map): Feature names display when the user hovers-over a state, county, or town.

When all 3 layers are selected in the layer-control (and added to the map) in state, county, town order: Feature names display when the user hovers-over a state, county, or town.

Problem:
When all 3 layers are selected in the layer-control (and added to the map) in town, county, state order): state names display (when the user hovers-over a state).  Town names do not display (when the user hovers-over a town). It appears that the toolTips for Towns are inert (on hover-over).

Comment: Thanks TomazicM for the nice editing!

Comment: So what would be the desired behaviour?

Comment: What about counties and states relationship? Counties cover the whole state, so state name would never be displayed if county has priority. Please edit your question and explain the logic of displaying names more in detail.

Comment: Desired behavior:  
When all 3 layers are selected in the layer-control - in any order: Feature names should display when the user hovers-over a state, county, or town.

Comment: Hi TomazicM.  Problem definition revised:
When all 3 layers are selected in the layer-control (and added to the map) in town, county, state order): state names display (when the user hovers-over a state).  County names display (when the user hovers-over a county).  Town names do not display (when the user hovers-over a town). It appears that the toolTips for Towns are inert (on hover-over).

Comment: Sorry, but from the code above and your description it's still not clear what should happen. Since there is no image, I imagine that counties cover the whole state, so it's impossible to display state info, since counties cover the state and there is always some county under the mouse when it's over some state.

Comment: My main goal is to make the names of all 3 entities (at least of ‘towns’) available (if towns are on the map) regardless of the order the user selected them (in the layer control).

I was hoping that, with the right ‘opacity’ setting, that the names (for features in all three feature collections displayed on the map) could be made available (by hovering over them).

You mentioned ‘priority.’  Is there a way for me to order the layers (or change the priority)? Then perhaps I could remove this user-dependency (i.e., the order that the user selects the layers in the layer control)?